# Print multiple sentences from a paragraph in separate lines

Tags: python

Whish to change the document below into a txt file (with text) and enter the file changing it so that every sentence is on it's own line. I tried with open() and get an error. Anyone know how to handle this one?

When I write the following I get an IndexError: string index out of range

```
document = "Hello World. Goodbye World"
def sentence_separator(document):
    pos = 0
    for char in document:
        if char[pos] == ".":
            char[pos] = "\n" 
        pos += 1
print(sentence_separator(document))
```

Desired output is each sentence on its separate lines:

```
Hello World
Goodby World
```

Comment: Is it acceptable solution to use `replace()` e.g. `document.replace(".","\n")`?

Comment: Will your document ever have 'My name is C.S. Lewis' in it?

Comment: You're iterating two times: `char` is going over every element of `document`, and then you try to access `pos` position in `char`. But `char` is already the char at that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `str.join`:

```
document = "Hello World. Goodbye World"

print('\n'.join(document.split('. ')))

Hello World
Goodbye World
```

Comment: I have a followup question: if the document variable is in fact a txt file with  text, in the same directory, I tried to change this text using the str.join and split method and get a error message. AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'.                                                            text = open("text_file.txt", "w")
text.write('\n'.join(text.split('. ')))
text.close()

Comment: Can you please write the whole code. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method with an argument to specify which character to split on, then print each element in the resulting array:

```
sentences = document.split('.')
print([s.strip() for s in sentences])
```

And the `s.strip()` gets rid of any extra spaces around the period.

Comment: I have a followup question: if the document variable is in fact a txt file with text, in the same directory, I tried to change this text using the str.join and split method and get a error message. AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'. text = open("text_file.txt", "w") text.write('\n'.join(text.split('. '))) text.close()

Answer (score 0):

You use str.replace to replace '.' by line returns:

```
def sentence_separator(document):
    return document.replace('.', '\n')
```

Comment: Don't really know where to insert that in the function. Could you please insert that in the function? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace function:

```
print(document.replace('.','\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do this:

```
document = "Hello World. Goodbye World"

def sentence_separator(document):
    sentences = document.split(". ")
    return "\n".join(sentences)

print(sentence_separator(document))
```

NOTE: The reason why you got this error **IndexError: string index out of range** is because with **for in** loop working with string, each incrementation takes one character for that string. So at this line:

```
if char[pos] == ".":
```

Imagine if 1 is the value of `pos` variable: it will try to find the second character of one character (sounds bad, it'snt?). Consequently, you get **IndexError: string index out of range**

Comment: have a followup question: if the document variable is in fact a txt file with text, in the same directory, I tried to change this text using the str.join and split method and get a error message. AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'. I wrote this: document = open("text.txt", "r")

def sentence_separator(document):
    sentences = document.split(". ")
    return "\n".join(sentences)

print(sentence_separator(document))

Comment: Okay! This error means that 'split' method is not related to a file object. String instead. So, in order to read the content of your file, put this 'document_content = document.read()' just after opening your file in document variable. That is it! A file object has a 'read' method that... reads a file content! (If you find my answer useful, please upvote it or something more ;-))